# Generar diferentes informes en PDF con diferentes nombres en base a una consulta

Tags: vba, pdf

Tengo una base de datos que genera un informe en formato PDF y lo guarda con un nombre específico en una ruta específica (el nombre del archivo PDF es el DNI del interesado, la fecha del informe y el nombre del informe).
El caso es que cuando la consulta en la que se basa el informe ofrece más de un resultado me guarda todos los informes en un solo archivo PDF.
Cómo puedo hacer para que guarde los archivos por separado, cada uno con su nombre??

El código que uso :

Public Sub ImprimirNotificacionSinSuspensión()

```
'Notificacion sin suspensión
Opcion = 1 'Correos
SubOpcion = 1
Mensaje = "¿Guardar Notificación sin suspensión AI-1?"
Estilo = 36
Respuesta = MsgBox(Mensaje, Estilo)
If Respuesta = vbYes Then
    If IsNull(FIRMA) Or IsNull(CARGOCASTELLANO) Then
        MsgBox "Falta Firma"
        Exit Sub
    End If
                
Dim myPath As String
Dim strReportName As String
Dim Dni As String

DoCmd.OpenReport "Acuses recibo", acViewPreview

Dni = Reports![Acuses recibo].[Dni] 'to access the field for the value on the report

myPath = "V:\Aplicaciones\Andromeda\Acuses de recibo\"

strReportName = Dni & " - " & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & " - Acuse NOTIFICACIÓN SIN INTERVENCIÓN (AI-1).pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath + strReportName, True
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Acuses recibo"

DoCmd.OpenReport "Notificacion sin suspension", acViewPreview

Dni = Reports![Notificacion sin suspension].[Dni] 'to access the field for the value on the report

myPath = "V:\Aplicaciones\Andromeda\Enviar a Portafirmas\"

strReportName = Dni & " - " & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & " - NOTIFICACIÓN SIN INTERVENCIÓN (AI-1).pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath + strReportName, True
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Notificacion sin suspension"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "Actualiza Notificacion Sin Suspension"
        CPrevi10 = 0
    
    MsgBox "Documento Guardado"
    MsgBox "Acuse de recibo Guardado"
    
    InputBox "Texto Corto en COND", "Anotación en COND", "INICIADA PV PSICOFISICA. PENDIENTE SANIDAD. ARCH EN PTES"
    InputBox "Texto Descripción en COND", "Anotación en COND", "INICIADO PROCEDIMIENTO DE PV POR PÉRDIDA DE APTITUDES PSICOFISICAS. PENDIENTE REVISION SANIDAD. ARCH EN PENDIENTES"
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Notificacion sin suspension", acViewPreview

        End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade el código en la misma, no como una respuesta. Te recomiendo leer [ask] completar el [tour]

Comment: Tu código genera 2 documentos PDF. Modifica las partes de `DoCmd.OutputTo` correspondientes según tus necesidades